# How does ghs.google.com know where to point me?

Tags: http-headers, dns, blogger, cname

I have a website registered through GoDaddy, and I decided to point blog.mysite.com to my Google Blogger page. The weird thing is: you're supposed to tell your alias to point to ghs.google.com instead of myblog.blogspot.com (the latter of which I tried to no avail).

I don't understand how ghs.google.com knows which blog to go to. I never specified this. Actually I *did* tell myblog.blogspot.com to redirect to blog.mysite.com, but I don't think that's how it made the association.

All I know is that ghs.google.com made this easy and convenient for me, but it just doesn't make sense and I don't have a clue how they did it (which doesn't make me content).

Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: Really? Next Youtube will be owned by Google... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTTP 1.1, the browser sends a Host header which contains the name of your domain, to ghs.google.com while requesting any content from it.

A GET request for example would look like

```
   GET /pub/WWW/ HTTP/1.1
   Host: www.w3.org
```

ghs.google.com will match the content of this header to determine what content (and for which site) it has to send back to the browser.